# Writing a batch script to perform differently on different days?

Tags: batch-file

I am in the process of setting up a batch script to do a specified action if the script was run on a weekday, and an alternate action if run on the weekend.

I am almost completely unfamiliar with writing batch scripts, but I know how to write my entire script except the logic I describe above. Can someone please answer both if it is possible, and if it is at least a framework of how to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what type of batch script you are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, you can do this:

```
if %date:~,3%==Sat goto :WeekEnd
if %date:~,3%==Sun goto :WeekEnd

:WeekDay
Dowhatever
goto :eof

:WeekEnd
DoSomethingDifferent
goto :eof
```

This example is the shortest you can write. Also if it's not on the weekend, execution just falls through to `:WeekDay`.

You can alternatively use the `if xxx ( xxx ) else if xxx ( xxx ) else ( xxx )` notation if you'd rather.

```
if %date:~,3%==Sat (
  goto :WeekEnd
) else if %date:~,3%==Sun (
  goto :WeekEnd
) else (
  goto :WeekEnd
)
echo Error^!
goto :eof

:WeekDay
Dowhatever
goto :eof

:WeekEnd
DoSomethingDifferent
goto :eof
```

It should never fall through to the `echo Error^!` statement.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem exactly, and I will definitely go with the first option because of how much more streamlined it is.